# Is it possible to view information of the "connected network" in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I was wondering if it was possible to "view devices in connected network" through native iOS API or through some sort of 3rd party API. Even if one exists, how would it work? If you're  confused, I'm thinking of some kind of "ipconfig" or "ifconfig" equivalent for iOS where I can just get a dump of all the IPs on a server. Apologies in advance if this isn't an appropriate question for this forum.

Comment: Which API are you using for your connectivity?

Comment: whether its private local network (WLAN) or some public (WLAN)?

Comment: @achievelimitless, not exactly sure what you mean, sorry if my question wasn't clear

Comment: Check my answer below, if it is not helpful, then consider my question. Actually I was asking which framework you are using in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IFADDRS to know about your host interface.Structure that describes an Internet host. [Know more about IFADDRS here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fi%2Fifaddrs.html) 
[This is how you get your host interface data](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fgetifaddrs.htm)

[Apple developers help manual for IFADDRS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)
Let me know if more info needed